# k8s-signed certificate not trusted within pod

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, x509

I'm trying to sort out certificates for applications deployed to a k8s cluster (running on docker-for-win, WSL2 on Windows 10 20H2).

I would like to use the DNS to connect to services, e.g. `registry.default.svc.cluster.local`, which I've verified is reachable. I created a certificate by following these steps:

1. Create an `openssl.conf` with content

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
encrypt_key = no
distinguished_name = req_dn
req_extensions = req_ext

[ req_dn ]
CN = *.default.svc.cluster.local

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = *.default.svc.cluster.local
```

2. Create csr and key file with `openssl req -new -config openssl.conf -out wildcard.csr -keyout wildcard.key`
3. Created a certificate signing request with

```sh
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: wildcard_csr
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: $(cat wildcard.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
EOF
```

4. Approved the request: `kubectl certificate approve wildcard_csr`
5. Extracted the crt file: `kubectl get csr wildcard_csr -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' | base64 -d > wildcard.crt`
6. Deleted the request `kubectl delete csr wildcard_csr`.

I've then started a pod with the `registry:2` image and configured it to use the `wildcard.crt` and  `wildcard.key` files.

In a different pod, I then tried to push to that registry, but got the error

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.default.svc.cluster.local:2100/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

So it seems that within the pod, the k8s CA isn't trusted. Am I right with this observation? If so, how can I make k8s trust itself (after all, it was a k8s component that signed the certificate)?

Comment: The assumption that k8s is passing its own certificates to the containers is only partially correct. The CA certificate you are looking for is `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`. Try using it to verify the registry and let me know if it works.

Comment: That certificate seems to be the one I need. How can I make it trusted?

Comment: You can copy it to `/etc/ssl/certs/` and run `update-ca-certificates`.

Comment: Is that seriously the way to do it for each pod?

Comment: @Matt shouldn't there be a way to configure this in yaml?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is the only way to do this. Kubernetes is generally not ingerating in containers and there are very little things that you can alter in yaml. Btw, you mentioned: `"In a different pod, I then tried to push to that registry, but got the error"` - is is impossible to pass this ca file using some flag or config file to the application? I belive this is how its usually done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this with changes to the yaml only: On my machine (not sure how universal that is), the CA certificate is available in the service-account-token secret `default-token-7g75m` (`kubectl describe secrets` to find out the name, look for the secret of type `kubernetes.io/service-account-token` that contains an entry `ca.crt`).

So to trust this certificate, add a `volume`

```yaml
name: "kube-certificate"
secret:
  secretName: "default-token-7g75m"
```

and to the pod that requires the certificate, add a `volumeMount`

```yaml
name: "kube-certificate"
mountPath: "/etc/ssl/certs/kube-ca.crt",
subPath: "ca.crt"
```